# Customized column power query editor - filters

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to add a column in the `power query editor` (using M as I want to show new column in table output) that should calculate following formula:

`Value of record` Column `Market Value` / Sum of Column `Market Value`

BUT this sum should only include rows where two other columns (in my case `Date` and `Account number`) are equal to the value in the `record/row` I want to calculate value for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are trying to achieve the same as doing a SUMIFS() calculation in an excel table but in power query?

This can be done in a couple of ways, but the simplest is with power query's "Group By" function. With this method you use Table.Group() to group the data by your two columns (Date & Account Number) and get the sum for all records. Then all you need to do is merge this value to the original table by referencing the group by step. This is equivalent to using a pivot table then doing a VLOOKUP on both the Date and Account number column.

Here is the M code:

```
let
// You're previous code here (replace the "Source" & #"Changed Type" lines)
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="my_data"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Account number", type text}, {"Market Value", type number}}),

// Group by Date & Account Number to sum each record
    #"Calculate Record Value" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Account number"}, {{"Value of Record", each List.Sum([Market Value]), type number}}),        // Replace #"Changed Type" in this line with the last step reference from your code
// Merge the group by value back to each record in the orginal table
    #"Merged Record Value" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Date", "Account number"},#"Calculate Record Value",{"Date", "Account number"},"sum",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
// Expand your new column
    #"Expanded Record Value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Record Value", "sum", {"Value of Record"}, {"Value of Record"})
in
    #"Expanded Record Value"
```

Hopefully this is helpful!
Please let me know if I have misunderstood your question or if this solution doesn't work for you.

Best regards
DougC

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! Inspired by your suggestion and will try to implement this.